# Window dragging laggy when connected to second 60Hz Monitor

Tags: gnome, graphics, multiple-monitors, monitor, framerate

Im on Ubuntu 22.04 (standard Gnome) and have 3 monitors (2x 144Hz via DP, 1x 60Hz via DVI)
Whenever i connect my third 60Hz monitor window dragging seems to be only in 60Hz.
If i have just my 2 144Hz monitors connected everything is fine and smooth.
Its kind of weird because my cursor moves at 144Hz, its just the window dragging.
I tried changing to nvidia drivers but its the same problem.
Anyone ideas?

Comment: wayland or xorg? please show output of `inxi -G`

Comment: @Esther xorg 'Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] driver: nouveau v: kernel
  Device-2: Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: nouveau resolution: 1: 1920x1080 2: 1920x1080
    3: 1680x1050~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NV134 v: 4.3 Mesa 22.0.5'

Comment: i just switched wo wayland and it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I changed from xorg to wayland and now it is butter smooth.